# The problem of "fine-grained locks and two-phase locking algorithm"

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

Question:
Given an integer array S of length N(N=100,000),there are M(M≥2) workers concurrently accessing and updating S.Each worker repeats the following operation 10,000 times:
Generate random numbers i and j, 0≤i, j<100,000. Update S such that S(j)=S(i)+S(i+1)+S(i+2). If i+1 or i+2 is out of bounds, then use (i+1)%N or (i+2)%N.
Hint: (a) Please consider concurrent protection,i.e.. reading S(i),S(i+1),S(i+2) and updating S(j) are atomic operations. *Refer to the two-phase locking algorithm. (b) Pay attention to the lock granularity. Each worker only reads 3 elements at a time and writes 1 element. There are a total of 100,000 elements. The probability that concurrent workers access the same element is very low. Using fine-grainted locks can reduce conflicts and improve concurrency. (c) Pay attention to the difference between read locks and write locks. (d) j may fall in the [i, i+2] range. (e) Addtional thinking: Will deadlock occur? How to avoid?

Regarding to this question, I tried using segmented locking technique. This method divides the shared array into multiple segments, each segment is protected by a mutex, and each thread only needs to lock the segment it accesses. Is this idea feasible or are there any better suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a feasible approach and by using segments you may not need mutexes at all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I'm not sure that the problem statement is completely air-tight, but it _seems_ to allow a thread to pick any `i` and `j` such that `i` and `i+2` and `j` all are valid indices into the array. If true, then that would disallow different threads from each working exclusively within its own segment of the array. So, if there are no mutexes, then how would you prevent multiple threads from concurrently accessing the same segments?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, it may not be applicable in this case so therefore I just said "may". In cases where the computation can be made on each segment without reading values from other segments that can be written to by other threads, no mutexes will be needed.

Comment: @3arong, Your questions about how to solve the problem are valid, but I don't like the problem itself because, how could you ever test a proposed solution? Even if you seed the PRNG so that it always gives the same sequence of (`i`, `j`) pairs, the outcome will depend on the order in which those pairs are applied, and if you allow multiple threads to concurrently apply them, then you cannot control that order.